# Match and delete some header strings on ruby

Tags: ruby, coding-style, header, rubygems, pattern-matching

I want to parse file and delete some header strings on ruby.

File(s) to be parsed looks like this.

```
---
some
text
text2
string
and
so
on
---
another string
and the other
```

And I want to remove

```
---
some
text
text2
string
and
so
on
---
```

this part.

**Edit:** I wrote a ruby code like this

```
file = File.open("test")
a = file.readlines
skip = 0
a.each do |line|
   if line.match("---\n")
     if skip == 1
       skip-=1
     else
       skip+=1
     end
   else
     if skip != 1
       print line 
     end
   end

end
```

This works, however, I think my code is dirty and should be cleaned.
How can I simplify my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a trivial task (assuming the file is well-formed).

Something like this:

```
lines = # read lines from file

is_header_mode = false
lines.each do |line|
   if line == '---'
     is_header_mode = !is_header_mode
   else
     puts line unless is_header_mode
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I added my ruby code, and can you give me some advice?